# How to use variables in the bounds of a variable-length pattern matching

Tags: neo4j, cypher

Given this Cypher query:

```
match p = ((a:User)-[*1..3]->(b:User))
```

How can I create a `d` variable to use in the upper bound of a variable-length pattern matching? For eg:

```
match p = ((a:User)-[*1..d]->(b:User))
```

Answer (score 0):

You can't.

Two solutions:

1. You construct the query string with the max length in it
2. You use the parameters afterwards, for eg

   MATCH p=(a:User)-[*]->(b:User) WHERE length(p) < 4
   RETURN p